# WiFi networks not showing in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, 20.04, network-manager, iwlwifi, nmcli

I tried to fix my broken grub from a Manjaro live USB using `grub-install` following which I couldn't connect to wifi networks. I can however use Bluetooth tethering to access internet. Wifi works normally in my Windows installation and in Manjaro live disk.
I tired to uninstall network manager and reinstall it. Now it shows no wifi networks.

I have tried to configure using netplan but none of the of the solutions worked.

`nmcli` command returns the following:

```
wlp58s0: unavailable
  "Intel 8265 / 8275"
   wifi (iwlwifi), A0:88:69:DC:7C:97, hw, mtu 1500
```

I have also tried `rfkill list all` in the command line. All of them shows no.

Comment: Same problem, I was using wi-fi w/o problems and then after a boot it desapeared. And nmcli doesn't show any wi-fi interface.

Comment: After update, wifi failed. No visible networks...